# Alternatives to LoadBitmap()

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, bitmap, static-libraries

Normally. the typical way of loading an image into a library is by including it as a resource file, and then by calling the LoadBitmap function in order to load it into the program.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to include a bitmap file as a resource into a (.lib file), only into a .dll file.  I was wondering what i can do if I need to include a bitmap into a library.

Here's what I have been thinking: I could create an array of bytes which could be cast to a bitmap.  I don't know if that's the best way to do it, and the exact details of how to deal with bitmaps and creating the HBITMAP object at the end are things I don't really understand now.  Of course, if there's a better way to do it, I'm welcome to suggestions.

Comment: Is it feasible to simply include a *.bmp file that can be packaged into the same exe or dll that your lib is linked into?

Comment: @RyanBemrose, not really.

Comment: A .bmp file's structure is almost identical to a bitmap structure, except for an additional header at the front. It would be trivial to write a program that reads a .bmp and outputs a source file containing the contents as an array of bytes, which can be used to initialize an actual bitmap.